# How to sum values from an Array of objects

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a data structure in Ruby as below:

```
[["N1-Alb",
  {'Sun, 05 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Mon, 06 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Tue, 07 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Wed, 08 Feb 2017'=>"0.25",
   'Thu, 09 Feb 2017'=>"0.03",
   'Fri, 10 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Sat, 11 Feb 2017'=>""}],
 ["N1-Cet",
  {'Sun, 05 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Mon, 06 Feb 2017'=>"7.8",
   'Tue, 07 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Wed, 08 Feb 2017'=>"0.00",
   'Thu, 09 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Fri, 10 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Sat, 11 Feb 2017'=>""}],
 ["N3-Tju",
  {'Sun, 05 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Mon, 06 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Tue, 07 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Wed, 08 Feb 2017'=>"3.15",
   'Thu, 09 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Fri, 10 Feb 2017'=>"8.0",
   'Sat, 11 Feb 2017'=>""}],
 ["N7-Mlp",
  {'Sun, 05 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Mon, 06 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Tue, 07 Feb 2017'=>"5.01",
   'Wed, 08 Feb 2017'=>"0.03",
   'Thu, 09 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Fri, 10 Feb 2017'=>"",
   'Sat, 11 Feb 2017'=>"4"}]]
```

How can I get sum for all Sundays, Mondays etc. up to Saturdays separately in to a Hash or an Array format?

The final hash should be:

```
result = { 'sun': '0', 
           'mon': '7.8', 
           'tue': '5.01', 
           'wed': '3.43', 
           'thu': '0.03', 
           'fri': '8.0', 
           'sat': '4' }
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>`

Comment: do you have a sample of code you wrote to try to get this to work? as a community, we like to see that you've done research and tried to implement a solution yourself and hit a wall.

Comment: @sagarpandya82: That is because `Sun, 05 Feb 2017` is a Date object. You can put those keys inside single or double quotes, the error will not happen!!

Comment: @eiko: I am currently trying it out. As it is quite urgent, I wanted to get some help from SO..

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". When asking we'd like to see where you searched and why that didn't work, or what you wrote and a detailed question about why that didn't work. You've only given us data and the required results but no evidence of trying which looks like you expect us to write code for you. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @theTinMan: The Code that I had been trying out while I posted this question was not completed. How could it be understandable if put that incomplete code? Though it could be against the rules, I understand..

Comment: Then follow the recommendations in the last link in my comment. We need to see some effort otherwise your question is considered too broad because it could be solved multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
days = [:mon, :tue, :wed, :thu, :fri, :sat, :sun]

result = your_hash.each_with_object({}) do |n, h|
  n[1].each do |key, value|
    h[days[key.cwday - 1]] = (h[days[key.cwday - 1]].to_f + value.to_f).to_s
  end
end
```

I updated the code to be more concise, per your request. This code exploits the fact that `nil.to_f == 0.0`, which may upset some stomachs.

Comment: Can we do this in a much concise way using `each_with_object` and `index`?

Comment: @RajeshOmanakuttan i updated the code to be more concise. thoughts?

Comment: Please don't add "updated" or "edited" tags to your text. Instead, incorporate the change into the text as if it was there originally, keeping everything readable. If we need to see what changed or when we can look at the revision history.